# C custom datatypes mapped to C datatypes grouped under a single struct

Tags: c, oop

I am implementing a message passing interface and one of the qualifications of its standards are custom MPI datatypes that map to say C datatypes. E.g `MPI_INT` maps to the C `int`.

So simple enough I would like to do:

```
typedef int MPI_INT;
typedef short int MPI_SHORT;
...
...
...
etc
```

But I want all these custom datatypes to be under a more general datatype called MPI_Datatype such that I could make a function prototype such as

```
MPI_Send(void*, MPI_Datatype)
```

where MPI_Datatype is one of MPI_INT, MPI_SHORT, etc

I'm not really sure how one would do this in C so if anyone has an idea that would be superb.

Comment: The closest approach in C is probably a structure containing a type tag and a union, together forming a disciminated union.  The alternatives are more complex than you're ready to deal with and don't really provide all that much benefit anyway.  The fact that the specification includes type `int` is worrisome — it isn't very portable or reliable (in theory).  More typically, a communication protocol would use explicitly sized types like `uint32_t` or `int16_t`, etc.  Or you could consider C++, although you'd still encounter at least some of the problems that you face in C.

Answer (score 2):

You may assign a unique ID number to each data type, and have both sides of the message passing line agree on it. Apparently you cannot compare data types, i.e. `if (data_type == MPI_INT)`, but you can compare IDs.

Comment: Yea but then I would then have to do something like a switch statement over the enum of datatypes and that would look ugly real quick.